# Why binding the new click event delays the current action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding a click event to an element (button A) which already has one. Currently, the click event only slides down a div (Div A). 
I'm hiding another div (Div B) on clicking the button A. 
however, I  notice the click event on button A gets delayed and Div A appears after a while. Does anyone have any idea why I see a delay.

My new click event is simply this:

I have tried adding mousedown instead of click

```
$('buttonA').click(function(){
      $('.nav-primary').hide();
});
```

There shouldn't be any delay in the existing click event execution.

Comment: Hi croninja! In order for us to assist you to our fullest extent, we need as much information or code relating to the problem as possible. In this case, it would be a big help if you provided us with a working code codepen.io , jsfiddle.net or StackOverflow Code Sample of your problem. That way we can see the problem for ourselves, debug the issue, and provide you with a solution ASAP. :)

Comment: `$('buttonA')` is an invalid selector

Comment: Please provide a [Minima, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. @GaryThomas it's always preferrable to have that as a stack snippet, not an offsite resource.

Comment: @Taplar that's just an example. I'm using the right selector.

Comment: @GaryThomas  - The code is given above. it's a simple click event. adding on top of a previous click event. unfortunately, I don't have access to that piece. That code itself works perfectly. It only creates a massive delay when I add this new click event on the same element so the original action gets delayed.

Comment: Show us your actual code then.

Comment: @VLAZ please see above comment.

Comment: @croninja your current code is not enough to understand what is wrong. This shouldn't cause a delay - there is nothing here that would. If you can give an example that reproduces the problem, then we can help, right now it's almost impossible.

Comment: @Taplar 
`
$('.ab_button').click(function(){
                 // hiding
          $('.c_046 .nav-primary a').addClass('ab_mask');
                   
});
`